# Get loaded picture URL from Coil

Tags: android, kotlin, coil

I have a question about getting the loaded picture URL from Coil. The reason why is because I'm using https://unsplash.it/200/200 to get a random image URL which will become something like [Image URL](https://i.picsum.photos/id/815/200/200.jpg?hmac=7zFtysk327pj5h65VOYejVs4MTbaHLX4cvGw1UL2A88), so how can I get the second URL when the image is loaded if I pass the first one to Coil? Here is the code I'm using:

```
SubcomposeAsyncImage(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(imageWidth)
                    .height(imageHeight)
                    .align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
                    .clip(CircleShape),
                model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
                    .data("https://unsplash.it/200/200")
                    .crossfade(true)
                    .build(),
                alignment = Alignment.BottomCenter,
                contentDescription = "Avatar Image"
            ) {
                val state = painter.state
                if (state is AsyncImagePainter.State.Loading) {
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier.size(10.dp),
                        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                    ) {
                        CircularProgressIndicator(strokeWidth = 2.dp, color = BlueColor)
                    }
                } else {
                    SubcomposeAsyncImageContent(
                        modifier = Modifier.clip(CircleShape),
                        contentScale = ContentScale.Fit
                    )
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I found. The trick is to use OkHttp to get the desired link since the first link returns a 302 status code (It will redirect to another link).

Here is the code:

```
fun randomAvatarUrl() {
val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .followRedirects(false)
    .build()
val request = Request.Builder()
    .url(avatarUrl)
    .build()
client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
    override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

    override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
        val originalURL = response.headers["Location"]
        if (originalURL != null) {
            Log.d("Tag", originalURL)
        }
    }
})}
```

Then pass originalURL to Coil and store it.